# Split non rectangle image into same sized blocks

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, sprite

I'm looking for an algorithm to chunk a non-rectangle image (i.e. transparent image) into blocks of (for example) size 16x16 pixels. The blocks may be overlapping, but the goal is to get the smallest amount of blocks.

### Example

[image: Original image]

[image: Goal]

### Summary

- Blocks must have equal sizes
- Blocks may be overlapping
- Smallest amount of rectangles is the goal

Thank you in advance

Comment: this looks like `bin packing` problem

Comment: Via [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/105164/covering-a-polygon-with-rectangles) you get to [this paper](http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/hoffmann/pub/h-cpfr-01a.pdf), which identifies your problem as the rectilinear p-centre problem. (It seems to be covered thoroughly in academia, but it is not very easy to find a ready-made algorithm for it.)

Comment: @MOehm: Those links are probably useful, but this doesn't appear to be the rectilinear p-centre problem, which (according to that paper) involves determining the smallest possible d such that a *given* number p of d\*d squares can be used to cover the given point set.  Here, d is fixed and p is unknown.

Comment: It seems like I may be missing something but is there another constraint to be minimised/maximised ?  Looking at the conditions listed it seems that the answer is 1; the smallest block which covers all pixels. I'm guessing there's a second constraint which is the total number of transparent pixels in blocks should be minimised or something. Is this correct ?

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Yes, you are right. When I saw the picture in the post I immediately thought of how maps are broken down into pages in an atlas, so the image of Italy was spot on for me. And it's hard to break a connection once it's made.

Comment: @DaveDurbin: The size of the blocks is fixed and given. In the example, it is 16pixels.

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of set cover. You could try an integer program solver, but there may just be too many possible blocks. The integer program would be amenable to column generation/branch and price, but that's an advanced technique and would require some experimentation to get it right.

I think that you could do pretty well with a greedy algorithm that repeatedly chooses the block covering as many pixels as possible including one boundary pixel.